# HidD_GetManufacturerString and similar functions return success, but do not modify the buffer

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, hid

I am having an issue with 3 functions (`HidD_GetManufacturerString`, `HidD_GetProductString`, `HidD_GetSerialNumberString`). The issue is that they return `TRUE` (indicating success), but do not modify the buffer (not even adding a terminator).

MSDN pages for the functions:

`HidD_GetManufacturerString`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

`HidD_GetProductString`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539681%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

`HidD_GetSerialNumberString`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539683%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Here is the code that actually calls the methods:

```
wchar_t manufacturer[MAX_SERIAL_LEN];
wchar_t product[MAX_SERIAL_LEN];
wchar_t serial[MAX_SERIAL_LEN];

ZeroMemory(manufacturer, MAX_SERIAL_LEN);
ZeroMemory(product, MAX_SERIAL_LEN);
ZeroMemory(serial, MAX_SERIAL_LEN);

HidD_GetManufacturerString(hFile, manufacturer, MAX_SERIAL_LEN);
HidD_GetProductString(hFile, product, MAX_SERIAL_LEN);
HidD_GetSerialNumberString(hFile, serial, MAX_SERIAL_LEN);

printf("Information for device %s\nManufacturer: %S\nProduct: %S\nSerial: %S\n\n", 
    DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath, 
    manufacturer, product, serial
);
```

`hFile` is opened like this:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(DevIntfDetailData->DevicePath, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

`DevIntfDetailData` is filled using `SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail`

`MAX_SERIAL_LEN` is defined as

```
sizeof(wchar_t)*127
```

Comment: Erm, how could you know that it isn't just an empty string when you use ZeroMemory?  Delete those calls and try again.

Comment: Like I said in the first paragraph, it doesn't even add a terminator, which it would on a zero character string. The buffer really isn't being touched

Comment: Maybe you missed the point.  How do you detect it writing a zero character when the buffer already contains zeros?

Comment: Because I zero the memory specifically because it wasn't adding a terminator

Answer (score 0):

Probably a driver bug.

I have a similar problem: The functions return `TRUE`, but the buffer is either not touched at all or it is filled with random garbage.

Here’s the catch: This happens only for my headset, and only while I am actively using its microphone via Skype/Teams/etc. Once I leave a call, the functions start returning ordinary names again.

This leads me to believe you’re seeing a faulty driver. Mine is the Windows standard headset driver on Windows 10 1907.